# Where is the plugin folder for Protege on an Apple Mac?

Tags: plugins, protege

The [Protege documentation](https://protegewiki.stanford.edu/wiki/Protege4Pizzas10Minutes) refers to a Annotation template plugin.

This plugin is not in the list of installed plugins, but is [available for download](https://code.google.com/archive/p/co-ode-owl-plugins/downloads).

The settings only gives a weblink under plugin registry.
So, where does the downloaded jar file go on an Apple Mac?